storybook can't compile my asset and tailwind in nextjs
i use version 8 of storybook and tailwind version 3 and also in nextjs 14.
i followup here for configuration storybook and import my globals.css in .storybook/preview.ts
when i run storybook it can't compile tailwind. and return and error like this:
enter image description here
I noticed that these lines from my css files are not compiled into the storybook because when I manually compile the file using postcss-cli or tailwind-cli and import it into privew.ts, there is no problem.
But it is not a standard way and it causes other problems in my project.
Does anyone have a solution?
main.ts:
import { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/nextjs";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@chromatic-com/storybook',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-styling",
      options: {
        postCss: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/nextjs',
    options: {},
  },
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
}
export default config

preview.ts:
import { Preview } from '@storybook/react'
import '../src/styles/globals.css'
const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
}

export default preview

and postcss.config.js
/** @type {import('postcss-load-config').Config} */
const config = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

module.exports = config;

